# UPDATE Balance in Entity Framework using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a website that has balances & I used to update with a stored procedure:

```
UPDATE Account 
SET Balance = Balance + @Diff
```

And it works very well BUT now with C# and Entity Framework, I can only update the value by setting amount (loading value first).

I'm ok with loading value before the update BUT I don't like the generated SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Account 
SET Balance = 6.99
```

That sucks because if balance gets updated after read and before update (which can be 300ms in EF from load to save) then the balance my be changed in the process.

And to run within a transaction is not really recommended for EF since it causes dead locks.

So is there any way to do this correct with EF or do I need to update with the stored procedure?

Comment: What is the other update coming from? If a value can be updated from multiple points that you need to look into ways of getting those multiple points to co-ordinate their updates.

Comment: its few other applications all using same database

Comment: If the SP was working fine for this, why don't you call the SP from EF?

Comment: how can i call SP from EF (on save changes)?

Comment: If your isolation level isn't serializable your SQL statement doesn't guarantee consistency either.

Comment: in EF it all runs ONLY on SaveChanges so from a transaction point its very good. BUT i could not afford to have balance updated wrong if another application updates in the mean time, ConcurrencyCheck is perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ConcurrencyCheckAttribute`:

**Model:**

```
public class Account
{
    //other properties...
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public decimal Balance {get; set;}
}
```

**Balance update logic:**

```
while(true)
{
    balance += diff;
    try
    {       
        context.SaveChanges();
        break;
    }
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {     
        //balance was updated by someone else,
        //so we will get it's last value and try to update again
        context.Entity(balance).Reload();
    }
}
```